# installing rjags in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, jags

Installing rjags from RStudio in Ubuntu 14.04, I get the error message,

`configure: error: "JAGS module directory /usr/lib/JAGS/modules-3 does not exist."`

In usr/lib/JAGS there is modules-4.

I also can't install rjags from the console, because I get the error message,

`Problem with header file /usr/local/include/JAGS/Console.h`

However, apt-get install r-cran-rjags works, but then rjags can't be loaded in R because it is looking for libjags.so.3

Suggestions for installing properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Martyn Plummer's blog post](https://martynplummer.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/jags-4-0-0-is-released), the CRAN version of rjags has not yet been updated to work with JAGS 4.0.0, which I guess you recently updated.

You can either wait patiently for the CRAN update or you can download the updated rjags package from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/rjags/4/).

Comment: I guessed it had to be something along those lines that I was missing. Thanks for solving it.